# Meteor {{yield}} not displaying posts

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a `main.html` file also a `layout.html` file. Inside the layout it contains this code

```
<template name="layout">
<div class="container">
<header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'postsList'}}">Test</a>
    </div>
</header>
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
        {{yield}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have a `publications.html` file

```
    Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
    return Posts.find();
});
```

And a `router.js` file

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'layout',
 loadingTemplate: 'loading',
 waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});

 this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
 });
});
```

And then my `posts_list.html`

```
<template name="postsList">
 <div class="posts">
     {{#each posts}}
        {{> postItem}}
     {{/each}}
 </div>
```

Collection

```
    if (Posts.find().count() === 0) {
 Posts.insert({
 title: 'Twitter',
 author: 'Tom',
 url: 'http://twitter.com'
 });
 Posts.insert({
 title: 'Facebook',
 author: 'Mark',
 url: 'http://facebook.com'
 });
}
```

I'm getting an object error on my display page. It's not showing up my posts, just [object Object]. Any reason for this, is my route correct?

Here is an image of the error!

[image: Object]

Comment: That `[object Object]` means that where you think you've got a string, there's an object instead.

Comment: @pointy yeah thats my collection, ill post it in the question too to show you

Comment: Did you mean `{{> yield}}` instead of `{{yield}}`?

Comment: @CarsonMoore Thank you, that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{{> yield}}` instead of `{{yield}}`.

Long explanation: The `{{> ...}}` construction tells Meteor to render a template there; otherwise, it tries to convert to the result of calling a helper to a string.  The reason you're getting `[object Object]` is because the `yield` helper is an object; you can see that by logging it:

```
console.log(Blaze._globalHelpers.yield);
```

This results in ...

```
{viewName: "yield", renderFunction: function, __helpers: HelperMap, __eventMaps: Array[0], _callbacks: Object…}
```

Objects, when converted to a string, render as "[object Object]".  You can confirm this like so in your console:

```
foo = {blah: 1}
foo.toString()
=> "[object Object]"
```